# What's the return status of the exit code?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Which do we want to keep and which should be synonymed to the other?

[return-status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/return-status), with 118 questions, says:

> Use this tag If your question revolves around determining or utilizing the return status (exit code) of a command. Common syntax involves the $? variable and the && and || symbols.

[exit-code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exit-code), with 31 questions, says:

> The exit-code tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

---

## Additional data (as of 2019-02-17):

- ["exit code" is:q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22exit+code%22+is%3Aq) = 345 questions
- ["exit status" is:q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22exit+status%22+is%3Aq) = 277 questions
- ["return code" is:q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22return+code%22+is%3Aq)  = 130 questions
- ["return status" is:q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22return+status%22+is%3Aq)  = 35 questions

---

Wikipedia has ["exit status"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) with redirections from "exit code" and "result code"; there is also ["return code"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_code) aka "error code".

---

The [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html#Exit-Status) and the [zsh manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins) both use the term "exit status".

---

As [mentioned](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5192/whats-the-return-status-of-the-exit-code#comment9632_5192), the POSIX standard uses the term "exit status".

---

Let's go ahead and rule out [%ERRORLEVEL%](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743) :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the POSIX standard uses the term "exit status", which kinda straddles both.  In any case, I like "status" better than "code" as a code implies a specific meaning (other than success or failure), as in "errno".

Comment: Actually, the "new" way of waiting for processes, which "only" dates back to the mid-1980s, has a `siginfo_t` with _both_ "code" and "status", separately.

Comment: The man pages for `bash` and `ksh` both refer to _exit status_.

Comment: Wow; looks like we may need several synonyms!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After seeing the additional data, I'm leaning towards this idea:

- base tag: [exit-status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exit-status) (a new tag, utilizing the current [return-status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/return-status) excerpt & wiki)
- synonyms: [exit-code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exit-code), [return-status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/return-status), and [return-code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/return-code)

---

I've created the [exit-status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exit-status) tag and populated it with the [return-status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/return-status) excerpt and wiki (slightly modified to say "exit status" instead of "return status").

I believe the next steps are:

1. merge [exit-code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exit-code) into [exit-status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exit-status) and make [exit-code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exit-code) a synonym for [exit-status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exit-status).
2. merge [return-status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/return-status) into [exit-status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exit-status) and make [return-status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/return-status) a synonym for [exit-status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exit-status).
3. create [return-code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/return-code) as a synonym of [exit-status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exit-status)

Helpful link: [Moderator cheat sheet for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119377/307535)

Comment: This is good. I think this is the best solution. I wonder, though, if it's worth having `return-code` as its own tag, as it could be applied in other circumstances, possibly.  Hmm... probably not.

Comment: Agree with this one. I'll chip in another term: [return-value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17336915/3701431)

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I don't think `return-value` would be as useful as it would be on the StackOverflow site as it is a term mainly used in non-shell languages. In the shell, the `return` statement returns the _exit status_ of the most recently executed command from a function or dot script (or an explicit exit status).

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm well aware of how it's used within shell context. I'm just suggesting that as possible synonym, which may be used by those more used to programming terminology.  Like I already said, I sufficiently agree with Jeff's answer

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Contrary to my opinion about [tag:exit-code], I think [tag:return-value] would be misplaced. While the code/status returned is, by definition, a "value", it is not what most people, programmer or not, consider a return value in practice. The implication is that the called function/command "returns" a value, as in `a=myFunc(42)` executes `myFunc` and places some value into `a`. `a=$( myFunc 42 )` gives a return value __and__ an exit code.

Comment: A _return value_ is for functions; while an _exit status_ (or _exit code_) is for processes.  The key word in this distinction is _return_ (as distinct from _edit_).

Comment: It might be worth changing the question tag from *discussion* to *feature-request* to request a moderator to implement this suggestion. 14-0 seems quite close to consensus to me.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan I wasn't sure what the official process was, so I went ahead and bothered terdon in chat; I will work with him tomorrow morning.  In the meantime, I've updated the Answer with what I think the next steps are. If anyone sees this in the meantime, please correct me if I'm heading the wrong way!